# JS - Guardar datos de una instancia en sessionStorage

Tags: javascript

estoy practicando la parte del DOM.
La idea es que cuando presione en el **botón nuevo** del formulario, se cree una instancia y poder guardar los valores de los campos en el sessionStorage una vez presionado en el **botón Guardar**. *Tengo 2 archivos*: Un archivo que es para la clase **Vehiculo.js** / **Principal.js**

No se en que parte crear la variable para que sea global a todo el código, ya que de momento me guarda en el sessionStorage, pero al presionar por segunda vez en el **botón nuevo** y almacenar los valores me sobrescribe los valores ingresados.

```
window.onload = Principal;


var miVehiculo;

function Principal() {
    Formulario();
    cargarEventListeners();
    this.miVehiculo = new Vehiculo();
}

function cargarEventListeners() {
    // Variables
    var formulario = document.querySelector('#formulario');
    var crearVehiculo = document.querySelector('#nuevo');
    var anadirkm = document.querySelector('#aniadirkm');
    var guardarVehiculo = document.querySelector('#guardar');


    var matricula = document.querySelector('#matricula');
    var modelo = document.querySelector('#modelo');
    var color = document.querySelector('#color');
    var select_op = document.querySelector('#op-tipo');
    var fecha = document.querySelector('#fecha');

    // Evento crearVehiculo
    crearVehiculo.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // Instancia
        this.miVehiculo = new Vehiculo();
        console.log(this.miVehiculo);

        // Limpiamos el formulario a traves del metodo reset
        formulario.reset();
    });

    // Evento anadirkm

    anadirkm.addEventListener('click', () => {

        var kilometros = Number(document.querySelector('#kilometros').value);

        // Cast del valor que trae kilometros, seguido de una comprobacion para validar si es decimal
        if (esDecimal(kilometros)) {
            this.miVehiculo.aumentarKM(kilometros);
        }
    });

       // Evento guardarVehiculo
 
    guardarVehiculo.addEventListener('click', () => {

        var funciona = document.querySelector('input[name="funciona"]:checked');

        this.miVehiculo.Matricula = matricula.value;
        this.miVehiculo.Modelo = modelo.value;
        this.miVehiculo.Tipo = select_op.value;
        this.miVehiculo.Color = [color.value];
        this.miVehiculo._fecha_matricula = fecha.value;
        this.miVehiculo._funciona = funciona.value;

        sessionStorage.setItem('Vehiculo', this.miVehiculo.serializar());
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que tanto sessionStorage como localStorage almacenan el valor proporcionado en base a una clave. En tu caso, esa clave es "Vehiculo":

```
sessionStorage.setItem('Vehiculo', this.miVehiculo.serializar());
```

Por lo tanto, cada vez que presiones el botón de guardar vehículo se almacenará asociado siempre a la misma clave, y por tanto, el valor anterior que tengas, será sobrescrito.

El acceso a sessionStorage es global por defecto, da igual desde donde accedas.

Te dejo este otro ejemplo que reproduce el problema que estás teniendo al pulsar de segunda vez en guardar:

```js
sessionStorage.setItem('Vehiculo', 1);
sessionStorage.setItem('Vehiculo', 2);
console.log('Vehículo almacenado: ', sessionStorage.getItem('Vehiculo'));
```

Nota: Por las limitaciones de donde se ejecuta el código en StackOverflow (protección de acceso mediante sandbox) es posible que debas copiar ese fragmento para poder ejecutarlo en tu browser, no es que sea inseguro.

Cualquier duda, puedes dejar tus comentarios.

Comment: Hola, no se si tienes un tiempo para que puedas ver mi código. Poder enviártelo a tu correo.

Comment: ¿Podrías reproducirlo en algún jsfiddle/codepen o similar para que así más gente con la misma duda o problema puedan beneficiarse? Si es una práctica, entiendo que no debería haber problema, sino, contacta sin problema

Comment: Lo acabo de subir https://jsfiddle.net/akem1x/8cdgzonk/ el problema es con el evento del botón nuevo, cada vez que se presione cree una instancia y guarde los valores una vez presionado en el botón guardar.

Comment: @ChristopherMendivel si te he entendido bien, estás queriendo guardar más de un elemento en el sessionStorage? ¿es así? ¿o el problema es de otra parte?

Comment: Eso es, la idea era guardar mas de un elemento en el sessionStorage, aunque ya lo tengo resuelto esa parte, el problema viene ahora al momento de recoger los valores del sessionS..

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta, a mi entender, estaba mal planteada. Fíjate que el título indica "guardar datos de **una instancia** en `sessionStorage`".